# XCUItest: Detect current SKView

Tags: sprite-kit, ios9, coded-ui-tests

How can I detect the current SKScene in iOS9/XCode7 UItesting functionality?

I tried to set the `accessibilityIdentifier` of the SKScene to a identifier string in the init method of the SKScene, but that did not seem to show up in the UI test using

```
  XCUIElement *element = 
  [[[_app childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeWindow] elementBoundByIndex:0] 
    childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element;
```

> Question updated with a partially working hack, by adding an UILabel, below:

I add the following code to my SKScene

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{  
  // This is not detected by the test case.
  self.accessibilityLabel = @"SceneMenu";
  self.accessibilityValue = @"anything";
  self.isAccessibilityElement = true;

  // This is detected by the test case.
  self.currentScene = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.size.width, 25)];
  [self.view addSubview:_currentScene];
  self.currentScene.accessibilityLabel = @"SceneMenu2";
}
```

I can then detect "SceneMenu2" in my UI test case, but I can not detect "SceneMenu". How come? This is my test case:

```
-(bool)sceneMenuIsShown
{
  return [_app.otherElements containingType:XCUIElementTypeStaticText identifier:@"SceneMenu2"].count == 1;
}

- (void)testExample
{
  while (![self sceneMenuIsShown])
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible (according to Apple staff).
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25019